# Python script for retrieving Reddit posts works but returns blank results

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I've written a python script which is intended to :

- Call the Reddit API
- Retrieve posts and comments of the subreddit 'r/booksuggestions'
- Save the results into a CSV for further analysis

The CSV successfully creates but the content is blank. I've confirmed the credentials are correct and I don't get a 401 error etc (which I did before I adjusted the client ID to the correct one). I'm using the PRAW Reddit/Python library.

I seem to be using the correct subreddit name and have confirmed there are posts in the time period. What am I doing wrong?

```
import praw
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import csv
import datetime

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='my client ID',
                     client_secret='my secret',
                     user_agent='my agent')

# Get the subreddit of /r/booksuggestions
subreddit = reddit.subreddit("booksuggestions")

# set time for last 7 days 
end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
start_time = end_time - datetime.timedelta(days=7)

# Prep the CSV
with open("booksuggestions_data.csv", mode="w", newline="") as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ["type", "id", "created_utc", "author", "body"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    # Search for posts
    for submission in subreddit.search(query=None, sort="new", time_filter="week"):
        try:
            if dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(submission.created_utc) >= start_time:
                writer.writerow(
                    {
                        "type": "post",
                        "id": submission.id,
                        "created_utc": submission.created_utc,
                        "author": submission.author.name,
                        "body": submission.selftext,
                    }
                )

            # Search for comments in the post
            submission.comments.replace_more(limit=None)
            for comment in submission.comments.list():
                if dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(comment.created_utc) >= start_time:
                    writer.writerow(
                        {
                            "type": "comment",
                            "id": comment.id,
                            "created_utc": comment.created_utc,
                            "author": comment.author.name,
                            "body": comment.body,
                        }
                    )
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error processing {submission.id}: {str(e)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be an error in this code. However, since the CSV file is empty, the issue is most likely with the writing of the data.

Also, in your code, you're attempting to make a search using the "query=None" parameter. This means the search query is empty and will return all posts in the subreddit. You need to specify a word or phrase for a specific search query.

You can try with an example query like:

for submission in subreddit.search("book", sort="new", time_filter="week"):

This example query will return all posts containing the word "book" in the last 7 days. Please feel free to replace "book" with a different query word.

Comment: I am trying to retrieve 'all' posts and comments though, not only the ones that have a specific keyword